# Styled Component Semantic kit ( Form . Input )

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, styled-components

Hello I would like to know how I could change css with the styled component of the form. semantic input

I need something like this on hoover:

[image]

But I can't change the background color of the input and also the border color in both default

```
and hover:
export const FormCustom = styled(Form)`
&&& {
    background: #000;
}
`
export const FormInput = styled(Form.Input)`
&&& {
    color: red;
    background: transparent;
}
`
```

tried but to no avail

```
export const FormInput = styled(Form.Input)`
&&& {
    color: red;
    background: transparent;
}
`
```

my form:

```
<FormCustom size='large'>
        <Segment basic>
          <FormInput fluid icon='user' iconPosition='left' placeholder='E-mail address' />
          <FormInput
            fluid
            icon='lock'
            iconPosition='left'
            placeholder='Password'
            type='password'
          />

          <Button color='teal' fluid size='large'>
            Login
          </Button>
        </Segment>
      </FormCustom>
```

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-morning-hq5zq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this example link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-wind-qs8oz)

I have updated the CSS properties and made an effect on the hover of form-control using styled-component. Currently, I just set the color code based on image share by you, so you can change it to your desired color code.

Now on hover input control and icon color, both are changed as per your requirements.

You need to update the styled component as below

```
export const FormInput = styled(Form.Input)`
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 0.28571429rem;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0em 0em 0em rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.35) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0em 0em 0em rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.35) inset;
  input {
     border: none !important;
  }
  &:hover {
    border: 2px solid #7159c1;
    background: #333;
    i {
      color: #7159c1;
    }
  }
  &:focus {
    color: #000;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0.28571429rem;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0em 0em 0em rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.35) inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0em 0em 0em rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.35) inset;
  }
`;
```

Comment: for some reason on hoover gets two edges

Comment: @MykonSpt actually its a border of input, the library automatically creates div > div > input  so the border which you see is actual input box order, so I just made few changes in the styled component so issue resolved. please verify the link, code is updated. https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-wind-qs8oz

Answer (score 4):

You can use `&:hover` to define hover.

```
   export const FormInput = styled(Form.Input)`
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      &:hover {
        border:1px solid #ff0000;
        border-radius:5px;
      }
    `;
```

[temporary sample sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-component-semantic-kit-form-input-r2e6o)

Comment: I didn't succeed it's like creating a new border

Comment: I used this in css to modify:

.ui.form input / .ui.form input: focus / .ui.form input: hover

but I can't do styled

Comment: I changed and put the css file with the tags that modify

but with styled it looks like it creates a new border.