# Toggle button / decrease width grid and div Semantic React

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a menu that will have a size and when you click the button it will decrease the width to 50px

ie I will have a menu with button and icons and when clicking the button will appear only the icon

but i'm having a hard time how do i decrease the width of my div and how would it work on the semantic grid

code:

```
function Menu() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true); // declare new state variable "open" with setter
  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setOpen(!open);
  };
  return (
    <Grid style={{background: '#eee'}}>

    <Grid.Column computer={2} tablet={4} mobile={5} style={{background: '#000', padding:'0', height:'100vh'}}>

    <div style={{background:'#000', width:'100%', height:'100%'}}>

    </div>
    </Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column width={14} style={{background: '#eee', padding:'0'}}>
          <Button icon onClick={handleClick}>
            <Icon name="align justify" />
          </Button>
    </Grid.Column>
   </Grid>
  );
}
```

css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#root,
.App,
.ui.grid{
  height: 100vh !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding:0 !important;
}
```

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-kepler-cxj4x

Comment: is this you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-silence-63gi8

Comment: please let me know do you want something specific will do it.

Comment: Yes, that's it, but I'm racking my brains about the grid because the content would have to fit not just the menu either

Comment: great!!!... let me post the answer here...also post the answer regarding to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59639573/5783700

Comment: yeahhh thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decrease the width of div when state of open being change on button click, please review [demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-silence-63gi8)

> App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid, Button, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./style.css";

function Menu() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true); // declare new state variable "open" with setter

  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <Grid style={{ background: "#eee" }}>
      <Grid.Column
        computer={2}
        tablet={4}
        mobile={5}
        style={{
          background: "#000",
          padding: "0",
          height: "100vh"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            background: "red",
            width: open ? "100%" : "calc(100% - 50px)",
            height: "100vh"
          }}
        />
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column
        computer={14}
        tablet={12}
        mobile={11}
        style={{ background: "#eee", padding: "0" }}
      >
        <Button icon onClick={handleClick}>
          <Icon name="align justify" />
        </Button>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
}
export default Menu;
```

Comment: From what I saw I'll have to change the width of the grid so that the content also moves to the side and not just the menu?

Comment: @MykonSpt, please refer link https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-flower-qdqjw

Comment: actually we provided the width of the grid computer, tablet, mobile properties, so on button click, we can not change its original width, so i have provided one of the solutions to get reduce width.

Comment: Thanks bro I think I get it.

I will try to modify this in css using @media

for each screen size

if i have any questions can i ask you?

Comment: the first question came to me
is there any possibility of using
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px)

no styled?

meaning basically I was thinking about it
when it is open I would give a certain width for each screen type
and when it's closed too
using the media

or maybe it's better to use responsive and do for each type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205597/discussion-between-ankitkanojia-and-mykon-spt).

Comment: @MykonSpt let's move out discussion in chat.

Comment: hi bro based on your code i tried to do something with styledComponents to train and it worked out just had a little problem could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651668/styled-component-react-semantic-props-and-calc